# .NET Compact framework (C#) : Add checkbox to Listbox

Tags: c#, compact-framework, listbox, checkbox

I would like to add a checkbox control to a listbox control.

The listbox has to contain A couple of tasks, and I have to check if a tasks has been opened before.

I have a code sample, but it adds the checkbox as an object, not as a control

```
while (reader.Read())   
{                    
   CheckBox c = new CheckBox().Enabled = false;
   c.Text = reader.GetString(0) + ". " + reader.GetString(1);

   try 
   { 
      if (int.Parse(reader.GetString(2)) > 1) c.Checked = true; 
   } 
   catch(Exception ex)    
   {

      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);    
   }    
   listTasks.Items.Add(c);
}
```

Can someone help me out

Thnx,
Ruben

Answer (score 12):

The Compact Framework doesn't support the CheckedListBox control. You could use a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) with the [CheckBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx) property set to true.

Comment: Ruben, you should mark it as a correct answer then. Phaedrus, it helped me too, thx.

Answer (score 1):

A list box only supports a collection of string ListItems.

Adding a checkbox to it in that manner will result in the checkbox.ToString() value appearing.

You might want to look at the "CheckedListBox" control though I'm not sure if that exists in the CompactFramework.

Answer (score 1):

The [Resco Mobileforms Toolkit](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/details.aspx?comp=SmartGrid&p=WindowsMobile) allows you to do this. The package isn't but it does have this functionality (As well as a fair few other useful bits that make CF apps feel a lot better than the standard Windows Mobile apps).

*N.B. I know this question was asked a long time ago, but we've recently been asked to write new software for one of these devices so I figure that even if you no longer need to solve this problem there are others out there that might benefit from this.*

Answer (score 0):

Your only other option using stock controls is to use Panel and perform the layout manually, and set AutoScroll true.  You can subclass Panel to expose your own Add/Remove type method to perform the layout when Items are added and removed.  You can use something like the swatch below to layout a list.  With this approach you can now compose your list with any kind of Control, but you loose programmatic convenience of the ListBox. I suppose you could add such functionality into the Panel subclass if necessary.

```
        public static void VerticalListLayoutStrategy(Panel panel)
    {
        int top = 0;
        foreach (Control control in panel.Controls)
        {
            control.Location = new Point(0, top);
            control.Width = panel.ClientSize.Width;
            top += control.Height;
        }
    }
```